# SIGSEGV: Program doesn't execute sequentially

Tags: c++, gdb, execution, segmentation-fault

My program receives a SIGSEGV and I am trying to debug. The strange thing is that when I use gdb to go line by line, the program is not following what I think should be the normal execution flow.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char * str_reverse(char * s);

int main (int argv, char ** argc){
    char * strinput;

    fstream finput;
    fstream foutput;

    finput.open(argc[1], ios::in);
    finput >> strinput;
    finput.close();

    foutput.open(argc[2], ios::out);
    foutput << str_reverse(strinput);
    foutput.close();

    return 1;
}

char * str_reverse(char * s){
    int len = 0;
    while (s[len] != '\000') len++;
    char * rev = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        rev[i] = s[len-(i+1)];
    rev[len] = '\000';  
    return rev;
}
```

This is what I see in gdb:

```
18      foutput << str_reverse(strinput);
(gdb) n
19      foutput.close();
(gdb) n
21      return 1;
(gdb) n
11      fstream foutput;
(gdb) n
21      return 1;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

By the way, the program does what it is meant to do correctly: it opens a file, reads a string and saves it reversed in another file.

Comment: Side note: you switched `argc` and `argv`. `argc` should be the *c*ount of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the program is not following what I think should be the normal execution flow.

I don't see any evidence of that. As far as I can see, your program *is* following the normal execution flow, *then* crashes after `main` returns.

This is happening because you have an uninitialized pointer `strinput`, and you write to the *unpredictable* location where that pointer points to.

It so happens that in your execution environment that pointer points somewhere on stack, so you corrupt your stack, which then causes you to jump to a bad address, causing the crash.

Comment: Oh yes, that too.  Probably even more severe than the error I've spotted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I execute my program using gdb, why does it goes through lines 21 -> 11 -> 21 ?

Comment: On line 21, just before returning, the local objects `finput` and `foutput` need to be destructed. I am guessing that GCC "assinged" line 11 to one or both of the destructors (and your GCC is probably fairly old).

Comment: That should be it. Thanks again!